# events doesn't work with the InvokeCommandAction

Tags: mvvm, silverlight-4.0, triggers, webbrowser-control, interaction

i am using a webbrowser control and interaction-triggers , and there is some events which don't work like ScriptNotify and LoadCompleted is this an limitation or there is something i should do 
Thanks